# In ASP.NET MVC, Data exchange between Model and View is possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a option to pass data between Model and view in ASP.NET. If it can be accomplished how? This was asked in an interview !!!

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure this is a very valid question. The model and view do not exchange data. But instead, the view simply presents the model data.

Comment: I agree with mcbros. MVC addresses the concept of "separation of concerns". The view shouldn't care **how** it gets the data from the model, it just presents the data that is within the model. It is up to the controller to populate the model with data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... well, the view is either typed, which means the object that represents the model is directly accessible, or the controller returns a ViewBag with data or anything else the view needs to render. That's the whole point of the model-view part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of MVC is that the data(Model) should be shown to user (View) by use of Controller. Even if the view is typed, your still need the model to bind to it.  Even to create a ViewBag, you need the controller action to fill it...